# Flipboard's pagination

Tags: android, pagination

I am bit reluctant in asking this question because since the initial days of stackoverflow, things have changed a lot and I find almost every other question being closed as not constructive.

But just as a programming exercise, I want to brainstorm ideas about paginating the content the way flipboad does.

Doing is on the client side using Paint.breakText() requires significant computation and often, the results aren't very accurate, slightly off.

The other way could be to break the text on server side but that would be easier for iOS compared to Android because of the sheer fragmentation in Android.

Your ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip

but creating your own using your ideas and algorithms can be better so you can start here:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html